# Client/server Swing program getting stuck when using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a problem with my Java program. I have this codes:

**Host.java**:

```
public class Host {
protected static void start(JFrame window) {
    ServerSocket server = null;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket();
        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port);
        server.bind(addr);

        Socket socket = server.accept();

        window.setVisible(false);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Incomming(socket.getInputStream()));
        thread.start();
        thread.join();

        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        [...]
}
}
```

**Incomming.java**:

```
public class Incomming implements Runnable {
private DataInputStream is;

public Incomming(InputStream is) {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();

    this.is = new DataInputStream(is);
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            int n = is.readInt();
            if(n == -1) {
                break;
            }
            byte[] b = new byte[n];
            is.readFully(b);
            [...] // working with bytes
        }
        System.out.println("Stream closed.");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        [...]
    }
}
}
```

**Client.java** is very similar to Host.java, it uses Incomming.java for socket.getInputStream() too.

So the problem is: the client connects to the host, but when it should show on server side and also on client side the MyFrame window, it doesn't load it fully. And the close button of old JFrame windows (on both sides) doesn't do anything.

I tried to remove the line with `thread.join()`, and then the MyFrame window loads completely and close buttons work, but it throws me exception with `socket closed` message, so the client is no longer connected to the host.

How could I fix this problem?
Thanks for replies.

Comment: If both client and server are using `Incomming`, then the first thing they both try to do is read from the input stream. Of course that will deadlock if nobody writes to the stream first... And what's the point in starting a new thread and then immediately call join on it?

Comment: first I'm wondering about running thread and just join for it!!! so it doesn't make sense use threads here , the GUI is because your GUI thread is run as same as _working with bytes_ process, so run the _byte process_ with another thread and let GUI has its thread too.

Comment: It is GUI code with 'join()' in it, so almost certain to fail.  If it was a console app, join() has only an average chance of causing problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Thread#join will block until the thread dies. This is preventing you from closing your window, as you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.
2. You `accept` an incoming socket, start a new `Thread` to process that socket and then promptly close the socket (most likely before the thread has had a chance to even start reading from it). Instead, close the socket inside the thread, once it has competed processing the stream

**Updated**

Swing is a single threaded framework.  This means that all interactions with the UI (creation, modification) MUST be executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Any operation that blocks this thread will stop the EDT from processing events, including repaint, mouse and keyboard events.

Instead of passing the socket's input put stream to the thread, you should pass the socket.  This passes responsibility for the management of the socket to that thread, freeing up you current thread.

Then in your `Incomming` class, you should grab a reference to the input stream of the socket, perform what ever actions you need to and the, finally, close both the input put stream and socket when you are done.

```
protected static void start(JFrame window) {
        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket();
            SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port);
            server.bind(addr);

            Socket socket = server.accept();

            window.setVisible(false);

            // Pass the socket to the thread to allow it to perform the work
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Incomming(socket));
            thread.start();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //...//
        }

    }

public class Incomming implements Runnable {

    private final Socket socket;

    public Incomming(Socket socket) {
        //?? What's this for, this is VERY wrong
        // UI Interaction should ONLY occur within the context of the EDT
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

        this.socket = socket;

    }

    public void run() {
        if (socket != null) {
            DataInputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    int n = is.readInt();
                    if (n == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    byte[] b = new byte[n];
                    is.readFully(b);
                    //...//
                }
                System.out.println("Stream closed.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {
                // Finally clean up...
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You **MUST** read [**Concurrency in Swing**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

If you intend to update the UI while processing the socket, you will most likely want to use a `SwingWorker` instead of a `Thread`.  This provides additional functionality to make it easier to sync updates back to the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: I have to use .join() method, because how I said, the sockets would close without that. So with what should I replace that? The client has to stay connected with server to end of whole program.

Comment: No, the socket closes because you close it before the thread has had a chance to run. Pass the socket to the thread and close within the thread once it has finished processing it

Comment: When I do this, it throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try to use `socket.getInputStream()` in the `run()` method of `Incomming` thread.

Comment: I'm not at a PC right now, at without a sample of your code, its difficult to supply suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your program means there's a single "path" of execution. At no point do you have 2 threads doing things at the same time. This is because you've called `thread.join()`, which waits for the thread to exit. Meaning that either the code in the `Incomming` class is executing, or the code outside of it is.

To get your UI to load, you are going to need to run 2 threads at once, which means rethinking the way your network connections are handled.

The first step is to handle closing the socket inside of the `Incomming` class. This will take care of the `SocketClosedException` caused by attempting to read from a closed socket.

The second thing you could do, is to communicate between the UI and `Incomming` class differently, as a Thread interrupt is a good way to wake a thread up from a long running network read, but provides no information as why you're waking the thread up. The simplest way to do this would be to have a boolean flag on the `Incomming` class that gets set when you call a function.

ex (please forgive the pseudo code):

```
class Incomming

    Socket socket;
    volatile boolean running;

    run():
        while( running ){ 
            try {
                 /* stuff */
            }catch( InterruptedException e ){
                 // nothing here
                 // we are just waking up the
                 // thread to unblock io
            }
        }
        socket.close()

    stop():
        running = false;
```

Comment: Perhaps I still do not understand how to split my program into 2 different Threads. Could you help please?

Answer (score 0):

1. thread.join() will block your current thread until the thread ends
2. socket.close(); will be executed before your thread ends. you have to move this code block into your thread run() method.