# Program freeze when calling Server method in Java

Tags: java, server

I have a basic `GUI` in `Java` where there is a `JButton`,I have given a functionality to start the `Server` with that button. But when I click the button the program freezes. Is it because of the `while loop`? If so how can I overcome this?

`Server Code`

```
 void connect_clients()
{
    try {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7700);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out =
                            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date().toString());
                }

                finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test_Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   
}
```

Comment: in while(true) - what is true, what are you evaluating in while

Comment: the loop listening forever for the clients who want to get connected.

Comment: Yes, it is because of the while loop. You'll have to do one of two things: create a new thread for the server program and start it when the button is pressed or make the handler set a flag to cause the main loop of your program to start listening on the socket.

Comment: without the while loop,can more than one client connect to the server?

Comment: You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, which is responsible for processing the Event Queue. Like all the other questions on the subject, you need to use some kind background thread, maybe a SwingWorkerif you intend to update the UI. This type of question gets asked 3+ times a day, so forgive me if I sound unforgiving, but there are plenty of similar questions and answers laying around

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419941/jframe-blocked-after-creating-socket-connection/25420058#25420058) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602685/client-server-swing-program-getting-stuck-when-using-threads/17602977#17602977)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is freezing because you are blocking the UI thread. You need to post this on a separate thread:

```
public void postListen()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            connect_clients();
        }

    }).start();
}
```

Call that method instead and it should run the connect_clients() method on a separate thread. The new thread will block until a client connects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is method explanation of [ServerSocket.accept()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()):

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The
> method blocks until a connection is made.

Until there is data input to socket, your program will freeze. If it's another problem, please check your logs. There may be another problem.

Comment: So what is the way to get out of this freeze?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. What else are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want the Clients to get connect to the Server and a `Powershell Command` gets executed when the admin clicks on any Client which is connected to the server.

Comment: You should see some printing when data comes to port `7700`